Cospectrality of square grid minors
I'm working on an interesting computational game theory problem. One way to dramatically improve the runtime is to develop a computationally efficient invariant that can characterise the graphs I'm working on. In particular, all graphs I need to analyse are minors of square grids. I've stumbled across spectral graph theory, but am by no means an expert; I do think they have good potential for relatively efficient computation (at least compared to isomorphism tests), but I do not really understand how to even start trying to prove that there are no such cospectral graphs. Has anyone looked into this before?
Other suggestions for potentially computationally efficient graph invariants are also more than welcome.
